# Can I restore my laptop to my company's domain after formatting?

Tags: windows-7, security, format, windows-domain

Right now my laptop is using Windows XP Professional 32-bit, and I have a copy of Win7 Pro 32-bit that I want to install. I would prefer a clean install, as I do not need any of the software on my XP installation, and want to avoid any possible problems carrying over.

My computer is on my company's Windows domain (in the format ComputerName.CompanyName.local). Because we are a small company, our IT dept is outsourced and it will be another week before IT is able to visit and set my computer up on the company domain. I would prefer to get this done now on my own, but I do not have any of the system-wide administration privileges.

I know in the past I have tried this (just with new XP installs, not Win7) and I remember that I could not get myself back on the domain. Is security still set up this way for Windows accounts? Is there any way to back up my credentials/certificates before formatting so I can log back into the domain after formatting?

Comment: I'd wait for your IT to come. You need administrator privileges to do this and if things go wrong you'll be without your machine until they do anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply put, don't do it. If you can't put your computer back on the domain, you will not be able to do much. You also have no idea if there are things they do that you have no idea are going on.